# how to redirect the trace window output to a file in CANoe

Tags: can-bus, capl, canoe

i would like to get all the data present in the trace window to my text file, even log recording can help but it can't display date and time in that file, so i've a plan to copy entire trace window to file.

i've tried to do ctrl+a and paste in notepad, but it is just copying some sort of area only not all.

i would like to know is there any chance to redirect how trace window is printing like that i can see in text file, or at least is there any way to copy entire file and paste in text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pretty-print it to the write window using CAPL:

```c
on message *
{
  int i;

  write("[%07.3f] %03X", this.time / 100000.0, this.id);
  for (i = 0; i < this.dlc; i++)
    writeEx(0, 0, " %02X", this.byte(i));
}
```

And then export it to a file.

---

Or you write it directly to a file.

Comment: Hello sergej, Your solution is good. What if I want to print big array(let's say size is 1000). I am trying it and getting message like - WRITE WINDOW QUEUE LOST. and some data is appended with the warning message. Can you please suggest how to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The trace windows just display the data, you configure it in the Measurement Setup.

But be aware that this will be only a part of the data anyway. There is a buffer where CANoe stores the data for the Trace window. You can configure the type of this buffer (memory or hard disk) and its size. Go to `Options -> Measurement -> Data History` to change your settings.

You can also configure the size of the visible data range there. But even with a `very long` range and a large 200 GB buffer, there might be a possibility that some data will not be available, because the Trace works as a ring buffer deleting the old data on overflow.

If you need the complete data, you should enable the Logging in the Measurement setup. Yes, the data files will be not human-readable. You will then need to open them in the Offline Mode in CANoe to analyze them. The timestamps will be of course logged, so you can easily use them for your analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I would suggest logging the necessary data into a CSV and then analyzing using Excel. You can make use of the File Access CAPL functions like openFileWrite for the same